How can I estimate unknown parameters in a linear model?
In the paper "Linear Pushbroom Cameras" by Gupta and Hartley they introduce a linear parametric model (equation 12):
$$
K(V_x,V_y,V_z,f,p_v,\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1/V_x & 0 & 0 \\
-k(fV_y + p_vV_z)/V_x & kf & kp_v \\
-kV_z/V_x & 0 & k
\end{bmatrix}
R_z(\alpha)R_y(\beta)R_x(\gamma)
$$
where $R_x$, $R_y$ and $R_z$ are the orthonormal 3x3 rotation matrices in an intrinsic Tait–Bryan rotation sequence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix.
Given a $K_{3x3}$ that is estimated from experimental data, the aim is to recover the parameters: $V_x,V_y,V_z,f,p_v,\alpha,\beta,\gamma$.
They derive a QR like decomposition:
$$
K = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
L_{11} & 0 & 0 \\
L_{21} & L_{22} & L_{23} \\
L_{31} & 0 & k
\end{bmatrix}
R_z(\alpha)R_y(\beta)R_x(\gamma)
$$
That recover all the parameters.
However in my case $f$ and $p_v$ are known.
They mention that an iterative parameter fitting algorithm may be used with the above solution as a starting point to get a more exact solution that respects known parameter values, but no details are given.
How could I implement such an iterative parameter fitting algorithm in my case?
